# Lazarus error - how to store result of integer in textbox?

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus, type-conversion

I'm trying out a very simple program in LAZARUS to multiply two text box values and store the result in a third one. This line is what I'm using.

```
txtA.Text = IntToStr( StrToInt(txtA.Text ) + StrToInt(txtB.Text) );
```

Unfortunately I get an error stating it's illegal.

Is this a fault on my part or a bug in Pascal?

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assigments in Pascal uses `:=`

try this

```
txtA.Text := IntToStr( StrToInt(txtA.Text ) + StrToInt(txtB.Text) );
```

Comment: Good catch! Quicker than me, anyway. :)

Comment: What was I thinking??!! I've used Pascal for a very long time and I had to make this silly blunder. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I also tend to use IntToStr() also, but you also have the option of using format() - which is preferred for strings that might be translated.